# Input date value and compare with existing table

Tags: laravel, date, validation

I'm trying to develop a program with `Laravel`. I have created a table ‘`tbl_holiday`’ like below: 
[database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83Rhn.png)
I have created a form containing 02 input (date) types named ‘`from_leave`’ and ‘`to_leave`’.
I want to check these 2 inputs value(date) with the database table ‘`tbl_holiday`’ having the condition:

If the previous day of ‘from_leave’ match with ‘`tbl_holiday.holiday_date`’
Or next day of ‘`to_leave`’ match with ‘`tbl_holiday.holiday_date`’
The message “`Invalid`”.
Else
Message “`Valid`”.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want to compare if there is any matching holiday_date in between the from_leave and to_leave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use wherebetween and check the number of data available in the collection.

```
$from = $request->from_date;
        $to = $request->to_date;
        $dates = YourModel::whereBetween('holiday_date', [$from, $to])->get();
        if($dates->count() == 0){
            return "valid";
        }else{
            return "Invalid";
        }
```

Comment: Great help. Thank you.

Comment: Select the best answer in your opinion to support comnunity bro.